# "Convert regions extracted from wav audio file into Flac audio file " python using FFMPAG in Django

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg

Regions extracted from wav audio file have "Invalid duration specification for ss"
For Example in my case duration is in this format

`[(0.006000000000000005, 1.03), (2.0540000000000003, 4.870000000000003)]`

This is for converting regions into Flac format.

```
     class FLACConverter(object):
         # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """
         Class for converting a region of an input audio or video file into a FLAC audio file
    """

     def __init__(self, source_path, include_before=0.25, include_after=0.25):
        self.source_path = source_path
        self.include_before = include_before
        self.include_after = include_after


     def __call__(self, region):
        try:
            print("regions to convert in flac:{}".format(region))
            start = region
            end = region
          #  start = max(0, start - self.include_before)
            start = list(map(lambda x: tuple(max(0, y - self.include_before) for y in x), start))
            end = list(map(lambda x: tuple(y + self.include_after for y in x), end))
            temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.flac', delete=False)
            command = ["ffmpeg", "-ss", str(start), "-t", str([tuple(x-y for x, y in zip(x1, x2)) for (x1, x2) in zip(end, start)]),
                       "-y", "-i", self.source_path,
                       "-loglevel", "error", temp.name]
            use_shell = True if os.name == "nt" else False
            subprocess.check_output(command)
            print(temp.name)
            #subprocess.check_output(command, stdin=open(os.devnull), shell=use_shell)
            read_data = temp.read()
            temp.close()
            os.unlink(temp.name)
            print("read_data :{}".format(read_data))
            print("temp :{}".format(temp.name))

            return read_data

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            return None
```

I expect the output of `/var/folders/p1/6ttydjfx2sq9zl4cnmjxgjh40000gp/T/tmpwz5n4fnv.flac` but it returns an error

> CalledProcessError at /

````
Command '['ffmpeg', '-ss', '[(0.006000000000000005, 1.03), (2.0540000000000003, 4.870000000000003)]', '-t', '[(0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5)]', '-y', '-i', '/var/folders/p1/6ttydjfx2sq9zl4cnmjxgjh40000gp/T/tmpuyi5spat.wav', '-loglevel', 'error', '/var/folders/p1/6ttydjfx2sq9zl4cnmjxgjh40000gp/T/tmp0vdewoyd.flac']' returned non-zero exit status 1.```
````

Comment: Why don't you use [python-bindings for ffmpeg](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python)?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar why I use python-bindings for ffmpeg because I didn't know how to use it ?I think problem is in duration format how I can change its format according to "-ss" .

Comment: On terminal it shows: Invalid duration specification for ss: [(0.006000000000000005, 1.03), (2.0540000000000003, 4.870000000000003)]

Comment: Well, I would have to look into it. Maybe I post an answer if I cloud figure it out. Are you running it on linux? @maryam-mehboob

Comment: No,its on MacOS @NafeesAnwar and Thankyou for your reply.

Comment: Okay, and what is your input to `__call__` method?

Comment: I have wav audio file from which I extracted speech regions these regions are passed to __call__ method.

Comment: It was difficult for me to understand how you input the region you want to extract from `.wav` file. But the problem is clearly that you are giving input to `ffmpeg` in form of tuples which is not acceptable. However, [here](https://gist.github.com/nafeesanwar/0dfe2e8dd82cd15e8c5bb219c7b0e600) is a working example I just created. Thank me later if it is some help :) or :/